# Проверка формата фото gif или png/jpg

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telegram

уважаемые пользователи Stackoverflow

Я искал в интернете свой вопрос, может плохо искал, но расскажу что я хочу у вас спросить.
Можно ли как-то узнать какой формат фотографии/файла загружаешь?

К примеру у меня есть бот в Telegram, и я для своей команды использую библиотеку [nekos.py](https://github.com/Nekos-life/nekos.py). Там файлы **gif/png** выбираются **случайно**, я точнее **не могу указать параметр** что я хочу **gif** или **png/jpg**.

Можно ли как-то отслеживать что библиотека подгружает?
Если к примеру в ссылке **.gif** в конце то бот отправляет **send_animation**, а если jpg/png то **send_photo**

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['waifu'])
async def send_randavatar(message):
    your_name = message.from_user.username
    hugimg = nekos.img('waifu')
    await bot.send_animation(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'@{your_name}')
```

Если **.gif** в конце

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иначе если **.png/jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: Я использую библиотеку aiogram.
Upd: на второй картинке используются команда, не для упоминания пользователя, но суть остается одна и та же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не забудь добавить `import os`

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['waifu'])
async def send_randavatar(message: types.Message):
  your_name = message.from_user.username
  hugimg = nekos.img('hug')
  extension = os.path.splitext(hugimg)[1]
  if extension == '.jpg':
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'@{your_name}')
  elif extension == '.png':
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'@{your_name}')
  elif extension == '.gif':
    await bot.send_animation(message.chat.id, hugimg, caption=f'@{your_name}')
  else:
    await message.answer('Нет картинки')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно данный код переделать под этот?
https://pastebin.com/MLs6XYw8

Чтобы работал как из этого (https://pastebin.com/MLs6XYw8) но и проверяло .png/.jpg/.gif в конце ссылки.

Comment: @Riktik, так как на данный вопрос был дан ответ, то будет правильным отметить его как решенный и создать новый, изложив в него суть, потому что отредактированный под новый запрос код не будет отображать решение для заданного вами вопроса

Comment: @Riktik, если вы считаете мой ответ полезным (и в других своих темах, где вы приняли мой ответ), то можете нажать соответствующую кнопку слева от ответа (треугольник вверх). Спасибо